# ASCX and ASPX Mayhem.

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, ascx

**BACKSTORY**
I am building a module that extends a .NET web app that I did not develop. All I know is that if I create a "view.ascx" file, populate it with the appropriate vb .net html and javascript code and put that file in the right place, that some good stuff is going to happen. Im having issues though.

My Goal, enable a web based TWAIN scanning utility.(I'm using a scanner to get a picture of the sole of the foot of a patient.) The scanning plugin (DynamicWebTwain) has the ability to set some http form fields and call a post method to an action page (aspx) file. The action page should then use those fields to store the file and make write a record in SQL with a pointer to the uplaoaded file destination and associated that with the patient chart id. The uploaded file name, storage path etc are all composed of data that sits in variables in the application mentioned above.

**ISSUES**

1. The view.ascx file (which encodes the reading of the application variable instances, the plugin embedding and the JS triggers) is loaded one time when the application loads. Therefore, the patient specific information, captured in a form is not actually available unless I reload the page. This of course is because you cant specify the patient demographics before the application is opened.
2. As a result of item 1. I am unable to set form fields with meaningful information and as such cannot pass it to the actionpage.aspx and upload and save everything properly in the filesystem and DB in the first pass.

**WORKFLOW SUMMARY**

1. Patient enters, dr loads web app. at this time the variables pertaining to the Patient are empty. the control is not reloaded at any point and those variables remain unchanged (blank) in my module as the Dr. navigates through the app. Dr. puts in PT name and DOB and clicks next which goes to the Scanner form.
2. Scanner module has not refreshed variable data. Dr. Takes scan via plugin, triggers JS to set and drive scanner, is presented with a Save button, Save button sets form fields and calls the action page.

**ATTEMPTED WORKAROUNDS**

1. Point the action page to the ascx file, in other words call myself - **FAIL** - Would love a good explanation of why this is not OK.
2. Re-evaluate tha variables within the actionpage.aspx file. ( well to do that i tried using the same references in the headers as found in my view.ascx file

   "<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false"
   Inherits="DriveWorks.Live.Parts.Modules.LiveModuleControl" %>
   <%@ Import Namespace="DriveWorks.Live.Parts.Theme" %>"

And of course this did not fly - **FAIL** -  If I could somehow talk to the application again from the actionpage.aspx file, i.e. call another ASCX page that would revaluate the variables and give me back the results, then that might solve my problems. Would love a good explanation on feasibility and approach with code samples.

Still green please be kind and Mind you the web app that I am building the module for is a black box to me..

Comment: Make the Twain plugin send *all* the field data?

Comment: TWAIN plugin does not have accurate field data. TWAIN plugin could get variable data pulled from the VB.NET portion of the ASCX but because that data is populated early in the lifecycle of the page, the variables don't have any values yet. The idea is that I somehow need to retrigger the evaluation of the variables after the TWAIN scan is performed.

Comment: Does the plugin offer any sort of events?

Comment: The plugin offers a buch of events.. They are : OnGetFilePath 
OnImageAreaDeSelected
OnImageAreaSelected
OnMouseClick
OnMouseDoubleClick
OnMouseMove
OnMouseRightClick
OnPreAllTransfers
OnPreTransfer
OnPostLoad
OnPostTransfer
OnPostAllTransfers
OnTopImageInTheViewChanged
OnTransferCancelled
OnTransferError
OnInternetTransferPercentage
OnInternetTransferPercentageEx
OnAfterOperate
OnBeforeOperate
OnOperateStatus

Comment: Cool. So it sounds like you can use OnPostTransfer. Then it's a matter of associating the uploaded image with the current page (and therefor client) until "Save" is clicked, right?